# How can I solve an "overflow evaluating the requirement" error with recursive iterator function?

Tags: rust

I'm making a Brainfuck interpreter. When i try to compile this I get a requirement evaluation error. It looks like it infinitely nests `TakeWhile<...>` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Instruction {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Left,
    Right,
    Out,
    In,
    Loop(Vec<Instruction>),
}

fn compile<'a, I>(mut iter: I) -> Vec<Instruction>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a u8>,
{
    let mut instructions = Vec::new();

    while let Some(c) = iter.next() {
        instructions.push(match c {
            b'+' => Instruction::Add,
            b'-' => Instruction::Sub,
            b'<' => Instruction::Left,
            b'>' => Instruction::Right,
            b'.' => Instruction::Out,
            b',' => Instruction::In,
            b'[' => Instruction::Loop({
                let mut depth = 1;
                compile(iter.by_ref().take_while(|c| {
                    match c {
                        b'[' => depth += 1,
                        b']' => depth -= 1,
                        _ => {}
                    }
                    depth != 0
                }))
            }),
            _ => continue,
        });
    }
    instructions
}
```

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut std::slice::Iter<u8>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>: Iterator`
  |
  = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`playground`)
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Iterator` for `&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut std::slice::Iter<u8>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>, [closure@src/main.rs:28:50: 35:18]>`
```

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: [It works in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2389574ceb8771e45db661cf735ad47a).

Comment: [It doesn't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c84fac5c705a35d95bb0a963d7c4b02e) when you actually try to use the function.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman ok, will do next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid creating an infinite type `TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<&mut TakeWhile<...` by forcing the iterator chain into a trait object:

```
let mut depth = 1;
compile(&mut iter.by_ref().take_while(|c| {
     // ^^^^
    match c {
        b'[' => depth += 1,
        b']' => depth -= 1,
        _ => {}
    }
    depth != 0
}) as &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &'a u8>)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See it running on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3f8b92a5059e314c3b2b051773aed69f).